# How to click on onclick link with image? Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I'm just learning how to webscrape dynamically using Selenium in Python. I'm currently trying to click on a link within the webpage to page forward over search results.

So far this is the code that I'm using:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\km13\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("http://www.congreso.gob.pe/pley-2016-2021")
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("img[src='/Sicr/TraDocEstProc/CLProLey2016.nsf/8eac1ef603908b5105256cdf006c41b1/$Body/0.AB2?OpenElement&amp;FieldElemFormat=gif']")
elem.click()
```

This is the HTML that corresponds with the element I'd like to click on:

```
 `<a href="" onclick="return _doClick('05257FB7005EB655.8eac1ef603908b5105256cdf006c41b1/$Body/0.A50', this, null)"><img src="/Sicr/TraDocEstProc/CLProLey2016.nsf/8eac1ef603908b5105256cdf006c41b1/$Body/0.AB2?OpenElement&amp;FieldElemFormat=gif" width="81" height="16" border="0"></a>`
```

From my somewhat limited knowledge of HTML this seems like the link is actually embedded in the gif which is why I tried to use the CSS selector that goes along with that image. But this did not work.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Update:
I changed my code by adding the following import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

And I changed the following:

```
elem = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img[src='/Sicr/TraDocEstProc/CLProLey2016.nsf/8eac1ef603908b5105256cdf006c41b1/$Body/0.AB2?OpenElement&amp;FieldElemFormat=gif']")
elem.click()
```

Now I get an error for "no such element."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an iframe.You need to switch to iframe first to access the element.Try below code.use WebDriverWait to handle dynamic element.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\km13\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("http://www.congreso.gob.pe/pley-2016-2021")

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME, 'ventana02')))
elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@onclick,'A50')]/img[contains(@src,'Sicr/TraDocEstProc/CLProLey')]")))
elem.click()
```

**EDITED**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\km13\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("http://www.congreso.gob.pe/pley-2016-2021")
driver.switch_to.frame(0)
elem=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[contains(@onclick,'A50')]/img[contains(@src,'Sicr/TraDocEstProc/CLProLey')]")))
elem.click()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I am now getting a timeout error. I tried increasing the wait time from 20 to 30 but still got this message.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting time out exception.I have just run the code and no exception at all.did you copy and paste the entire code?

Comment: My mistake, it works! I was trying to separate the two elements because I would like to be able to click on each link in the search results, scrape the content, return to the search page and then be able to navigate forward through the results. I guess I would just have to include the entire block of code every time I want to scroll through the page results? For example, if I wanted to navigate each subsequent page.

Comment: Yes, thanks so much for your help and the suggestion!

Comment: To learn more about WebDriverWait refer the link https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: For further information it is not necessary to every page have iframe.However if your locator matches the element in DOM but you are still getting unable to find element then you must check if there any iframe or not.Hope this helps.